# How to set decimal values in hive stack command

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to execute below hive stack command

select stack(2,'A',**10.1**, '2015-01-01','B',**20.123**, '2016-01-01');

But it is giving me error because of inconsistencies in decimal precisions, below is the error message

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'stack(2, 'A', 10.1BD, '2015-01-01', 'B', 20.123BD, '2016-01-01')' due to data type mismatch: Argument 2 (decimal(3,1)) != Argument 5 (decimal(5,3)); line 1 pos 7;
'Project [unresolvedalias(stack(2, A, 10.1, 2015-01-01, B, 20.123, 2016-01-01), None)]
+- OneRowRelation (state=,code=0)
```

Comment: show us the full hql. It is showing error in aliasname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast explicitly to `double` or `decimal` with required precision and scale:

```
hive> select stack(2,'A',cast(10.1 as double), '2015-01-01','B',cast(20.123 as double), '2016-01-01');
OK
A       10.1    2015-01-01
B       20.123  2016-01-01
Time taken: 2.818 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

hive> select stack(2,'A',cast(10.1 as decimal(5,3)), '2015-01-01','B',cast(20.123 as decimal(5,3)), '2016-01-01');
OK
A       10.1    2015-01-01
B       20.123  2016-01-01
Time taken: 0.066 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```